# foreach loop inside multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $new_items with following output in print_r:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 70494
                [weight] => 0.3000
                [Price] => 31.4400
                [url] => http://www.myshop.com
                [name] => Apple iphone
                [category] => Array
                    (
                        [parent_id] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 53
                                [1] => 81
                            )

                        [parent_name] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Mobile
                                [1] => Bluetooth  Devices
                            )

                        **[category_id] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 150
                                [1] => 1384
                            )**

                        [category_name] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => iphone 4s
                                [1] => Bluetooth Speaker
                            )

                    )

                **[media] => Array
                    (
                        [images] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => http://www.myshop.com/file_2111_316.jpg
                                [1] => http://www.myshop.com/file_2112_260.jpg**

                            )

                    )
```

How can i write a foreach loop inside another foreach loop so that I can obtain all values including [category_id] and [media][images] values.

This is to insert values in 2 separate tables.

My current code is:

```
foreach($new_items as $key => $value) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO   products(id,weight,price,cb_url,product_name) 
                            VALUES(:id,:weight,:price,:url,:name)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $value['id'], ':weight' => $value['weight'], ':price' => $value['Price'], ':url' => $value['url'],
                  ':name' => $value['name']));

    //second table insert
    $PID = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO temp_products(productid,catid) 
                            VALUES(:pid,:catid)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $PID, ':catid' => $value['category']['category_id']));
}
```

Everything is going fine, except that the catid column in table 2 is getting  the value "array" inserted in it, **where there are multiple items in the [category_id] array element** above. If only 1 item is present it inserts correctly. I need to insert [media][images] similarly.

Should we need to write a foreach loop inside the existing foreach loop? Or else how to proceed? Help sought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `category_id` is an array, you need another `foreach` loop:

```
//second table insert
$PID = $conn->lastInsertId();
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO temp_products(productid, catid) VALUES(:pid, :catid)");
if (!is_array($value['category']['category_id'])) {
    $value['category']['category_id'] = array($value['category']['category_id']);
}
foreach ($value['category']['category_id'] as $catid) {
    $stmt2->execute(array(':pid' => $PID, ':catid' => $catid));
};
```

Notice, by the way, that you only need to prepare a statement once, outside the loop. You should do the same thing with the first `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Thank you. But now only category id's with multiple items are getting inserted, but not with single item.

Comment: Who is the idiot who designed that data structure so that it isn't uniform? If there's a single item, it should put it in an array with one element, not as a string.

Comment: @ Barmar  You are absolutely correct. It is an xml feed coming from another company.

Comment: Of course you can. There's nothing special about `category_id`.

Comment: One last question, please. The images insert works fine except the $PID = $conn->lastInsertId(); is inserted as 2 for first item. Should we reset the last insertid after first foreach ?? How??

Comment: This code is inside the first `foreach`. So `$PID` should be the ID of the row that was inserted in the first INSERT.

Comment: I am doing it as a mysql transaction and $conn->commit(); is done after all queries have run..I know that after commit it will return to 0. Okay..i reset the  last insertid and now it is working fine. Thank you for your valuable support..

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying is wrong. Is it not getting the new `$PID` after each INSERT in `products`?

Comment: $PID2 = ($conn->lastInsertId()-1); Works fine.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. That's the ID of the row that was added just before the one that we just added.

Comment: I think you're confused about what `lastInsertId` is. It's not a loop counter. It's the value of the `auto_increment` column that was filled in automatically in the last row that was inserted. There's no reason why it can't be `2` the first time, if there's already a row with `productid = 1` in the table, or if there used to be one and it was deleted.

Comment: I have truncated all the tables and run $PID = ($conn->lastInsertId(). In images table (third insert) it was showing lastinsertid as 2. I think it is because after the first insert lasttinsertid changes to 1, in next insert 2 and so on..for each foreach loop..When i add $PID2 = ($conn->lastInsertId()-1); to the last insert it works fine.

Comment: Make sure you aren't inserting into any other table before you assign the variable, since it's the ID of the last insert into ANY table.

Comment: Thousands of programmers use that function without having to subtract 1. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I think you need to start a new question, and show the full code that's having this problem.

Comment: Okay..i will check my code once again and submit a question if needed.